# What does CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT actually do?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I'm experimenting with CMake and tried to create 2 packages: development and runtime. So I set a specific component to the `install` command.

```
install (TARGETS mylib
          LIBRARY
          DESTINATION /usr/lib
          COMPONENT lib)

install (TARGETS mylib
          LIBRARY
          DESTINATION /usr/lib
          COMPONENT dev)

install (DIRECTORY include/
          DESTINATION /usr/include/mylib 
          COMPONENT dev)

set(CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT ON)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
#component specific configuration
```

As specified in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackDeb.html#variable:CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT) the `CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT` set to `ON` generates multiple packages. But the default named single `mylib-0.1.1-Linux.deb` was generated.

But when I replace `set(CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT ON)` with [`set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL 1)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackComponent.html#variable:CPACK_%3CGENNAME%3E_COMPONENT_INSTALL) it generates the correct pacakges for each defined component.

So I am confused what `set(CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT ON)` actually is supposed to do if generating multiple packages is done by `set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL 1)`

Answer (score 3):

It does **nothing** :) It was a typo in the docs fixed in [this commit](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/e6460e7d40a0146d6580d41da17f64370ce9a092).

In fact, it's the completely internal variable of the `CPackDeb.cmake` module and user shouldn't bother about it at all.

Please, (always :) use the [latest docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL) ;)